# Moving Netbeans project to Eclipse and putting in the same SVN repository

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn

I had a Java project in Netbeans IDE, which I had to move to the Eclipse IDE. As we all know, the folder structure of both these IDEs is different. I already had the Netbeans version of my project checked-in on SVN repository.

Now, I want to use the same SVN location to check-in the Eclipse version of the same project with the same name. Since I created a brand new Eclipse Java project on my local and just copied the source files from Netbeans to Eclipse, I obviously do not have the '.svn' folders in my project.

How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just take your "eclipse" project and copy it back over the netbeans one - then commit the result
you will get both in 1 folder (if i understood your setup correctly)